Kotlin 2.0 equality on UInt? and UInt not working as expected
i have a weird behavior with the new Kotlin 2.0.0 compiler, see this sample code:
class A(val a: UInt?)

val list = listOf(A(2U))

fun main() {
    val lambda = { idx: UInt -> list.firstOrNull { it.a == idx } }
    for (i in 0U ..< 6U) {
        val e = lambda(i)
        println("result: ${e?.a}") // Always null printed
    }
}

See in Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/C_5lz7TDh
Why does the lambda call never return the element in case idx is 2?
Weirdly enough, it works if i swap the idx andthe it.a like here:
class A(val a: UInt?)

val list = listOf(A(2U))

fun main() {
    val lambda = { idx: UInt -> list.firstOrNull { idx == it.a } }
    for (i in 0U ..< 6U) {
        val e = lambda(i)
        println("result: ${e?.a}") // Works as expected
    }
}

See in Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/p74BU_rs1
The code worked just fine up until Kotlin 1.9.x
The issue arose after migrating to Kotlin 2.0
I don't think this is the expected behavior after a migration, but maybe i missed some documentation on Kotlin 2.0

Works fine in other target except JVM. Should file a bug.

it's seems to be about the nullable part, with !! operator it works as expected, e.g. ${it.a!! == idx}

The problem may be related to the changes made for https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew20.html#support-for-unsigned-primitive-types-in-functions-with-jsexport

Thanks for the comments, so this seems like a bug. Issue filed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-69282/
